# When to release a lite version of an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, release

I have created an iPhone application and I have submitted it to Apple and it is currently waiting for review and I have been debating with myself for the past half an hour if I should release a lite version of an app.

I was wondering when one should release a lite version of an app once the full app is in the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

You should deploy a "lite" app if you think it will get a lot more downloads than the paid full version, and the conversion rate from lite to paid is higher than the paid app sales cannibalization caused by people who are content to use only what the free lite app provides.  There is also possible advertising revenue that could be gotten from a free app if the download count is many digits in size.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should release a lite app as soon as possible. On my adventures through the app store, and looking at statics, you get more people downloading you free app than your paid app (no brainer of course).

If you do a good job on you lite app and get people interested, you'll find people converting to the fully paid app.